# Nano Thermal Printer

Tags: gpio, cups

I recently bought a [nano thermal printer](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2752) from adafruit to complete a [project](https://learn.adafruit.com/instant-camera-using-raspberry-pi-and-thermal-printer/overview) but I am having troubles with the printer. I though I had wired it up right on my Raspberry Pi A+ but wasn't able to get it to print a test page off the Raspian Jessie OS. I know the printer works because I can print the information sheet by pressing the button on the back. I have switched the RX on the printer to the TX on the pi and vice versa. I installed CUPS on another raspberry pi and put the SD card back in the A+ and still no luck. Theres lots of information on the tiny thermal printer not much info on the nano thermal printer. If anyone finds anything it would be a great help!

Thanks in advance,

Tyler

Comment: Does the printer work hooked up to the 'other' Pi?

Comment: I only have one pi that is compatible and thats the A+ the other pi apparently isn't compatible but I tried it anyway with no luck. Earlier I had it hooked up to ground and 5v and I tried to print a test paper and the whole pi crashed and a tiny bit of paper came out so I tried restarting it but it kept crashing (I assume a power draw issue) and a little bit more paper came out until I had a small piece with a bit of gibberish on it.

Comment: Just to clarify that was the A+ that had a little bit of paper come out

Comment: Is there anyway that you could share how you have it wired up, say by drawing us a circuit diagram?

Comment: @Mohammad https://s22.postimg.org/pt5myivfl/wiring.jpg         https://s22.postimg.org/84dw6wjoh/wiring2.jpg

Comment: Those photos do not show where the Pi is reviving power from, can you please elaborate on how the Pi is being powered? Also I believe that the ground on the Pi should connect to the ground on the printer as all serial communications require a common ground

Comment: Sorry about that @Mohammad, the pi was being powered by usb. As I've previously mentioned, I did hook it up to ground and 5v on the pi. I'll give it another shot and see what happens

Comment: Read my comment on your answer please

Answer (score -1):

Okay I got it printing! I attached it to 5v and ground and the pi. I Switched the RX from the printer to TX on the pi and vice versa. It wasn't getting enough power from the usb alone so I attached a battery pack to the other 5v and ground.

Comment: I think the real problem was you connecting the ground from your Pi to the ground on the printer, also can I post it as an answer to get those few points?